# Import XPdf into Visual Studio

Tags: import, visual-studio-2013, project, xpdf

I've been trying to figure out how to import the source from xpdf (http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) into Visual Studio Express 2013 so that I can utilize the pdftotext function. Could someone run me through the steps required?